# Problem with BrowserRouter, iterating the array incorrectly using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first React app project and I have a problem with importing content of the page using `<BrowserRouter>`.

I have 3 Material-UI Tabs `/lights`, `/animations`, `/settings`.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/lights" component={LightsMenu} />
        <Route path="/animations" component={AnimationsMenu} /> 
        <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsMenu} />
</Switch>
```

Tab nr.1 is different then others because im using file called `store.js` where is

```
export const devices = [
{
    id: "philips-hue",
    name: "Philips",
    description: "Magic RGB",
    voltage: "210",
    lights: "Philips HUE"
  }, (...)
```

This is how LightsMenu (`{devices}` from store.js) that doesnt work looks:

```
export default function LightsMenu ({ devices }){
  return (
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid item xs>
      <Paper style={styles.Paper} >
       {devices.map(([group, devices]) => (
          <Fragment>
            <List component="ul">
              {devices.map(({ lights }) => (
```

This is how SettingsMenu looks:

```
export default function SettingsMenu() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper style={styles.Paper}>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
```

I have tried to:

```
import LightsMenu from "./LightsMenu.js";
```

and

```
<Route path="/lights" component={LightsMenu} />
```

but I have this error:

```
TypeError
devices is undefined
LightsMenu
/src/Components/Layouts/LightsMenu.js:32:6

  29 | return (
  30 | <Grid container spacing={1}>
  31 |   <Grid item xs>
> 32 |     <Paper style={styles.Paper} >
     |    ^
  33 |      {devices.map(([group, devices]) => (
  34 |         <Fragment>
  35 |           <List component="ul">
```

How can I fix this?
[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-spence-r8ph3)

Comment: How are you passing `storejs` --> `devices` array to `LightsMenu` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
import { devices } from './store.js'

<Route
  path='/lights'
  component={() => <LightsMenu devices={devices} />}
/>
```

Also you are not iterating the `devices` array correctly using `map`.

Below is the working code:

```
  <Paper style={styles.Paper} >
   {devices.map(({lights}) => (
      <Fragment>
        <List component="ul">
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText id="switch" primary={lights} />
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <Switch
                  edge="end"
                  inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": "switch" }}
                />
              </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Fragment>
    ))}
  </Paper>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Im getting this error now: ```TypeError
arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
_iterableToArrayLimit
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.3300dc61.js:1
_slicedToArray
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.3300dc61.js:1
LightsMenu/<
/src/Components/Layouts/LightsMenu.js:34:20

  31 | <Grid container spacing={1}>
  32 |   <Grid item xs>
  33 |     <Paper style={styles.Paper} >
> 34 |      {devices.map(([group, devices]) => (
     |                  ^
  35 |         <Fragment>
  36 |           <List component="ul">
  37 |             {devices.map(({ lights }) => (
```

Comment: Can you share codesandbox link you are referring to?

Comment: I will put it in the Question Edit

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please look @b0bgetout. You were not iterating the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import devices from store.js

Add
`import {devices} from "./store";` in lightsMenu component.

Comment: Its not enough i think